# Linux Lubuntu 19.10 failing installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, lubuntu

I've tried installing lubuntu 19.10 0n multiple devices but every time i try installing i keep getting this output where it gives me an error message

`External command finished with errors. 
Command apt-get update finished with exit code 100. Output: Ign:1 cdrom://Lubuntu 19.10 _Eoan Ermine_ - Release amd64 (20191017.1) eoan InRelease Ign:2 cdrom://Lubuntu 19.10 _Eoan Ermine_ - Release amd64 (20191017.1)/New Folder/ Old InRelease Hit:3 cdrom://Lubuntu 19.10 _Eoan Ermine_ -Release amd64 (20191017.1) eoan Release Err:4 cdrom:// Lubuntu 19.10 _Eoan Ermine_ - Release amd64 (20191017.1)/ New Folder/Old Release Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs Reading package lists... E: The repository 'cdrom://Lubuntu 19.10 _Eoan Ermine_ - Release amd64 (20191017.1)/New Folder/Old Release' does not have a Release file.`

I have tried making new partitions, linuxswaps and erases but no luck. If anyone has any suggestions i would be glad to hear them, thanks in advance!
[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrXzn.jpg)

Comment: The "New Folder" in the apt repo path is concerning. Has the image worked before? How did you download and build the image? What medium (ISO, USB)? What hardware are you installing to?

Comment: Have you tried running Lubunu as a Live CD? You might want to try that, boot from the CD and install it from there. Worked for me few times.

Comment: @Andy Shinn, new folder is a folder that contains all my old os and past documents, just in case, I am using a USB boot which was configured with default settings in rufus Kingston g3 32gb flash drive 3.0. I am installing it on mediocre specs 2gb ram and Intel atom. I have used this boot iso before and had successful installations I'm not sure if its something wrong with the boot now or what but I don't have access to another computer to get a new boot.

Comment: @vssher I have not tried that, and I don't have any spare cds lying around also I do not have a computer to. Access it to